# WPF - Desktop Application - Custom Audio for Toast Notification not working

Tags: c#, audio, wpf-controls, toast

I have created a C# desktop application using WPF for sending a toast notification. I am using my own custom audio to play when the toast notification gets displayed. I found some problems where my custom sound is not getting played when the notification window is popped out.

I have used the following code to add custom audio to my notification.

```
        bool supportsCustomAudio = true;

        if (AnalyticsInfo.VersionInfo.DeviceFamily.Equals("Windows.Desktop")
            && !ApiInformation.IsApiContractPresent("Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract", 2))
        {
            supportsCustomAudio = false;
        }
        if (supportsCustomAudio)
        {
            notificationBuilder.AddAudio(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Audio/customaudio.mp3"));
        }
```

Am I missing something? Could someone please help me with the issue?

Comment: `ms-appx:///` is known not to work in WPF and according to [Custom audio on toasts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/custom-audio-on-toasts), only `ms-appx:///` and `ms-resource` are supported. So I am skeptical that you could use it in WPF.

Comment: I have using ms-appx:/// only in my WPF application. Can you please suggest why it is not working?

Comment: Do you mean you successfully use `ms-appx:///` in other part of your WPF app?

Comment: This is the only part of code where i am using ms-appx:/// to refer my custom audio  present in the project directory for the toast notification..

Comment: As far as I know, `ms-appx:///` does not work in WPF.

Comment: Can you please suggest the other way of adding custom audio to the toast notification?

Comment: I have no idea.